# gmock - testing mock method arguments

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I have following mock method:

```
MOCK_METHOD1(send, void(const std::vector<int>& data));
```

How to check if that method was called with a particular argument, for example `std::vector<int> vec{1,2,3}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mock object is named `mockObj`, this is how to you would match the argument with the desired vector:

```
std::vector<int> dataToMatch{ 1, 2, 3 };
EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, send(ElementsAreArray(dataToMatch.cbegin(), dataToMatch.cend())))
    .WillOnce(Return());
```

Answer (score 2):

According to gmock docs on [container matchers](https://github.com/google/googlemock/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#matching-containers), for the proposed use case, you could simply do:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, send(std::vector<int>{1,2,3}).Times(1);
```